# Nuxt-ts, vuex error: This dependency was not found in .nuxt/store.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

OS: Windows 10

*what am I already did*

Delete .nuxt and run "yarn run dev": **not work**

Delete .nuxt and run "npm run dev": **not work**

Change node version to 16.15.1 and 14.19.3: **not work**

**Team Repository, can not recreate the project.**

**I think because nuxtJS generate .nuxt/store.js with double back slash**

but I can not force nuxtJS to use forward slash

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                       friendly-errors 15:27:35  

This dependency was not found:                                                                                                                friendly-errors 15:27:35  
                                                                                                                                              friendly-errors 15:27:35  
* ..\store\signIn.ts in ./.nuxt/store.js
```

/.nuxt/store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const VUEX_PROPERTIES = ["state", "getters", "actions", "mutations"];

let store = {};

(function updateModules() {
  store = normalizeRoot(require("..\\store\\index.ts"), "store/index.ts");

  // If store is an exported method = classic mode (deprecated)

  if (typeof store === "function") {
    return console.warn(
      "Classic mode for store/ is deprecated and will be removed in Nuxt 3."
    );
  }

  // Enforce store modules
  store.modules = store.modules || {};

  resolveStoreModules(require("..\\store\\auth.ts"), "auth.ts");
  resolveStoreModules(require("..\\store\\profile.ts"), "profile.ts");
  resolveStoreModules(require("..\\store\\signIn.ts"), "signIn.ts");
```

*I don't know why it passes all require() to error at "..\store\signIn.ts"*

/store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({})
export const getters = {}
export const mutations = {}
export const actions = {}
```

/store/signIn.js

```
// /store/signIn.ts
import { getterTree, mutationTree, actionTree } from 'typed-vuex'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt-ts",
    "build": "nuxt-ts build",
    "generate": "nuxt-ts generate",
    "start": "nuxt-ts start",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.js,.vue .",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lintfix": "npm run lint:js -- --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-property-decorator": "^2.9.1",
    "nuxt-typed-vuex": "^0.3.0",
    "nuxt-web3": "^0.0.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^8.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder": "^0.21.3",
    "@types/vuelidate": "^0.7.15",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7"
  }
}
```

it's my first question, apologies if it unclear

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? On MacOS, the paths in `.nuxt/store.js` are with normal slash, not backslash.

Comment: Also, since nuxt 2.13 if I remember well, the `@nuxt/typescript-runtime` module isn't required anymore. Only the `@nuxt/typescript-build` is necessary. So you don't actually need to use `nuxt-ts` command, the regular `nuxt` command should work. Try it :)

Comment: @Kapcash I'm on Windows 10
Thanks for the comment, now I use `nuxt` instead of `nuxt-ts` and it's work! but stuck in the same problem at `This dependency was not found:  * ..\store\signIn.ts in ./.nuxt/store.js  `  : ( do you have any idea to fix this

Comment: And if you remove the `signIn.ts` file, it does compile? Honestly I have no idea why this fails :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after doing this

1. change node version to `12.17.0`
2. remove `.next`
3. remove `node_modules`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm run dev`